# How to start a virtual machine filled with qemu-nbd?

Tags: kvm, virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

I migrated a Windows OS (entire disk) to a virtual machine on another host (Debian with `qemu` and `kvm`). I used **Selfimage** to export the disk.

On the host, first of all, I created an empty virtual machine:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 myVM.qcow2 180G
```

And I imported the image by:

```
qemu-nbd -t myVM.qcow2 -p 1024
```

After 10 hours the image was exported. I stopped `qemu-nbd` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Now I don't know how to start the VM or how to add it with `virt-manager`!

Answer (score 1):

`qemu-img` creates a virtual disk, not a virtual machine. `qemu-nbd` allows you to mount a virtual disk image on the host. Nowhere in this process are you creating or importing VMs. Start by explaining what you want to do, and we'll be able to provide pointers

Comment: I want to migrate my sbs2003 from an old machine to a virtual machine on an modern machine.